# second monitor shown despite not having one

Tags: monitor, 22.04

Hi I recentliy updated to ubuntu 22.04. There I tried to connect a second monitor which didn’t work. Know after unplugging the monitor it constantly showes me that a second Unknow Device is connected. How do I remove that device.

Comment: Which additional monitor have you tried and how was it connected?

Comment: thanks for the reply after doing nothing for the last 4 hours, somehow the Problem fixed it self without me doing anything